# The definition of convergence of a sequence. Suppose $x_1,x_2,\dots\in [-\infty,+\infty]$ and $x\in [-\infty,+\infty]$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, definition

I am reading "An Introduction to Measure Theory" by Terence Tao.

In this book, there is no definition of convergence of a sequence.

Let $[-\infty,+\infty]$ be the extended real number line.
Let $x_1,x_2,\dots\in [-\infty,+\infty]$.
Let $x\in [-\infty,+\infty]$.
What is the definition of $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$?
If $x_1,x_2,\dots\in (-\infty,+\infty)$, then I know that definition from Calculus.

Suppose $x_i=-\infty$ for some $i\in\mathbb{N}$ or $x_i=+\infty$ for some $i\in\mathbb{N}$.  Is the following definition of mine ok?

1. Suppose $x\in (-\infty,+\infty)$. We write $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=x$ if:
   For any positive real number $\epsilon$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that if $n\geq N$, then $x_n\in (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$.
2. Suppose $x=-\infty$. We write $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=x$ if:
   For any real number $K$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that if $n\geq N$, then $x_n\in[-\infty,K)$.
3. Suppose $x=+\infty$. We write $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=x$ if:
   For any real number $K$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that if $n\geq N$, then $x_n\in (K,+\infty]$.

Comment: Not very clear... you can find the definition of *convergence of sequences* in e.g. T.Tao's Analysis I, page 128. See also [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence)

Comment: And see **Ch.6.2 The Extended real number system**, page 133-on.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you very much for your information. But I think it is the definition for $(x_n)$ and $x$ such that $x_1,x_2,\dots\in (-\infty,+\infty)$ and $x\in [-\infty,+\infty]$.

Comment: Anne Bauval, Thank you very much for your edit.

Comment: Your definitions are correct and can be unified: see (on Wikipedia) [Limit of a sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Definition_3) and [Topology of the extended real line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line#Order_and_topological_properties).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you very much for your comment and the links.